# How do you properly call useState within a React custom Hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to create a custom Hook that allows me to pass a value and subtract 1 whenever I press a button.  I'm currently getting the error that says

> React Hook "useLastPage" is called in function "handleLastPage" which
>   is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function

in the following code:

```
function usePrevPage (page) {
    const [lastPage, useLastPage] = useState(page)
    useEffect(() => {
        function handleLastPage(page) {
            useLastPage(page - 1)
        }
        handleLastPage()
    })
    return lastPage
}
```

My code mirrors the React Doc's custom hook example closely so I'm not sure how to call `useLastPage` within my custom Hook.  Following is the example from [React's Doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html#extracting-a-custom-hook):

```
function useFriendStatus(friendID) {
  const [isOnline, setIsOnline] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    function handleStatusChange(status) {
      setIsOnline(status.isOnline);
    }

    ChatAPI.subscribeToFriendStatus(friendID, handleStatusChange);
    return () => {
      ChatAPI.unsubscribeFromFriendStatus(friendID, handleStatusChange);
    };
  });

  return isOnline;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

React is confused as you are using `useLastPage` for the updator of `const [lastPage, useLastPage] = useState(page)`.

Try to change `useLastPage` to `setLastPage`.  You should use `use` prefix for hooks.

Check out the demo - https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-neumann-hgely

Comment: Thank you for the demo. How would I invoke usePrevPage by pressing a button? I keep getting "Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component" no matter where I call it from.

Comment: @Kevvv In this case, the hook looks unncessary as `useEffect` is for the life cycle while you want to handle an event, (life cycle hook's is not invovled). You can simply handle the click event within 'App' using `useState` as I did in this demo https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-proskuriakova-dxc98

Answer (score 2):

`useEffect` is similar to `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate`. It will run when the `Component` is being `mounted/updated`. To decrease the `lastPage` state value you can simply call its setter directly inside the useState callback. Also I suggest changing the setter prefix to `set` instead of `use`

```
function usePrevPage (page) {
    const [lastPage, setLastPage] = useState(page);
    useEffect(() => {
          setLastPage(page-1);
    });
    return lastPage;
}
```

If you want to change the value on button click then you need to write the handler outside `useEffect` and set that to the button's `onClick` prop.

Comment: The error message says that useEffect must not return anything.  Also, could you elaborate on having the handler outside of useEffect?

Comment: Sorry, the return should be for your custom Hook. Not the useEffect.

Comment: Ah ok.  Also, one of the rules for using Hooks is "Do not call in event handlers."  How would I use the Hook defined above to be triggered by a button?

Comment: Since this is a custom hook you have made here. You can use this anywhere throughout your react app. Your custom hook will basically act as a function which will take a value and return it after decrement by 1.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your main problem is that you are calling your set function `useLastPage` - The React linter looks for functions that begin with the word `use` and tries to 'lint' them as hooks. In this case `useLastPage` isn't a hook, it's the returned setter from `useState`. I suspect that if you call it `setLastPage` that will clear up the error message for you.